# Python pseudonymisation of sniffed mac adresses

Tags: python, scapy, packet, packet-sniffers, probe

I have a assignment where I have to pseudonymisate the last 3 bytes of every mac adress I'm getting back as probe requests. By that I mean to format a printed mac adress like this `ce:63:be:f5:04:00` to `ce:63:be:aa:aa:a1`everytime I'm sniffing. How can I do this in my python script?

```
from scapy.all import *

def PacketHandler(pkt) :
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :
        if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 4 :
            print("Client with Mac: %s probing for SSID: %s" % (pkt.addr2, pkt.info))

sniff(iface="wlan1mon", prn = PacketHandler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Scapy's `RandMAC()`

```
>>> a = "aa:bb:cc:00:11:22"
>>> a[:9] + str(RandMAC())[:8]
'aa:bb:cc:c5:ab:23'
```

Or simply craft the randomization yourself.
If you don't know string slicing in Python, look it up: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: NameError: name 'RandMAC' is not defined

Comment: Import it. `from scapy.volatile import RandMAC`